# How to know wheter a type is a reference type or a value type in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, types, reference, copy

How do you know whether a `type` is a `reference type` or a `value type`. For example, according to an about.com article (http://visualbasic.about.com/b/2005/10/29/when-is-a-copy-not-a-copy.htm) an `integer type` is always a `value type` while an `array type` may be a `value type` or a `reference type`. On the same note, when copying a `cookiecontainer` must one use the `clone()` method or does `=` work as well? That is will `=` create a copy or a reference of a `cookiecontainer`?

**NOTE:**
It seems to me that by how it is used in this code, `=` creates a copy.

From: http://howtostartprogramming.com/vb-net/vb-net-tutorial-52-httpwebrequest-cookiecontainer/

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Dim logincookie As CookieContainer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim postData As String = "referer=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.zybez.net%2Findex.php%3Fapp%3Dcore%26module%3Dglobal%26section%3Dlogin&username=" & TextBox1.Text & "&password=" & TextBox2.Text & "&rememberMe=1"
        Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
        Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
        Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)

        Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://forums.zybez.net/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login&do=process"), HttpWebRequest)
        postReq.Method = "POST"
        postReq.KeepAlive = True
        postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies
        postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        postReq.Referer = "http://forums.zybez.net/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login&do=process"
        postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
        postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length

        Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
        postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
        postreqstream.Close()
        Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse

        postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
        logincookie = tempCookies
        Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())

        Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd

        RichTextBox1.Text = thepage

    End Sub


    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://forums.zybez.net/index.php?app=core&module=usercp"), HttpWebRequest)
        request.CookieContainer = logincookie
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim theusercp As String = reader.ReadToEnd

        RichTextBox2.Text = theusercp

    End Sub
End Class
```

## UPDATE 1

From MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) all `classes` are `reference types` therefore making `cookiecontainer` a `reference type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you want:

```
dim x = 100
dim isValueType = x.GetType.IsValueType
```

Comment: This could be it, however I'm looking to do it inside the Visual Studio environment. Of course, I could write this code and display the type in a message box, but I'm wondering if there is one concise way to know without having to write temporary code.

Comment: i did not get you - did you want to know whether it's a value/reference type at runtime, or what?

Comment: then you can use "If GetType.IsValueType Then ..." clause to perform different actions, right?